# How can I ignore leading zero's in a RegEx capture?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a database which contains ID such as

```
        ID
000000000000000000000PBC_1164321
00000000000000000000000RP_395954
00000000000000000000000MOP_395954
00000000000000000000000395954
```

I want to get only the data after the leading 0's
something like this:

```
ID
PBC_1164321
RP_395954
MOP_395954
395954
```

I am testing it on https://regexr.com. I tried using `^(0*)` but it selects all the 0's. I want the opposite of it, not select all the leading 0 but everything after it. Kindly help.

I am not using any language such as Python and R. Just want to use regex to select/match anything apart from leading 0's

Comment: Try with `sub`.  You can specify the start of the string (`^`) followed by 0 or more 0's and replace it with `""`, `sub(^0*", "", df1$ID)`

Comment: can you try that on the link i used in the question. It doesnt recognize "sub"

Comment: There you need `^0*`  `sub` is a `R` function.

Comment: @akrun the ^0* is only selecting 0's, I want the opposite of that. select everything after the 0

Comment: You can try the pattern `"^0*"` at your link---all that link does is the regex matching. You might want to do a lot of things with regex matches--extract them, extract the whole string if there is a match, return a logical if there is match, replace the match, etc. `sub` is an R function that replaces (substitutes) the match. A nice way to remove 0s is to replace the 0s with nothing `""`. That is what akrun proposes.

Comment: Khsitij, did you try it? `sub("^0*", "", "00000000000000000000000MOP_395954")` returns `"MOP_395954"`, exactly what you were requesting.

Comment: How can I do this without using any python or R fucntions such as "sub" and "Replace". Use only regex for the whole thing? Is it possible?

Comment: Regex just matches. It doesn't *do* anything with the match. You want to do something, so you need more than just regex.

Comment: `([^0].*)` should work for you @KshitijYadav

Comment: @Gregor thats fine, how can i match anything except the leading 0's. I actaully want that only

Comment: Khsitij, okay, fair question. Where are you trying to do this? Without R or python or another programming language, you can do it in `notepad` or on a piece of paper ... which is obviously sarcasm and because I don't know more context.

Comment: @CodelessBugging thats excellent. Please answer this, iI will upvote and close this question.

Comment: @Toto, please read the rest of the comments before closing this as a dupe. The OP specifically asked about doing it without python/R, and while it is not clear to me what that means, it does suggest that more details are needed before knowing that this is a duplicate.

Comment: @KshitijYadav cool, glad I could help, but seems like I can't answer until the question is no longer flagged as a dupe

Comment: @CodelessBugging i dont think its a duplicate question. how can I un-flag this? Any ideas?

Comment: OK, done. But the comment that they don't use R or Python was said after I closed

Comment: @Toto Sure. Thank you.

Comment: @CodelessBugging please write the answer :)

Comment: @Toto, thanks for re-opening. For the record, though: *"without using any python or R fucntions"* at 15:30:49Z, your close was at 15:32:26Z. Perhaps it took a minute or so for it to register on the page ... yeah, that happens to me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match text after the leading zeros using `([^0].*)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `/[A-Z1-9].*/gi` [A-Z1-9] will match any character in A-Z 1-9 essentially not a 0, the dot matches any character and the star matches it 0 or more times. The tags match globally and case insensitive.

I initially attempted a solution similar to @Codelessbugging but was unable to get the site to process it correctly.

[Link to this solution](https://regexr.com/4bs2t)
[Link to CodelessBugging solution](https://regexr.com/4bs4j)

Comment: I think codeless and yours both are right. Since the software I am using does the interpretation one row at a time, it was able to parse it with what codeless presented.